# Meteor & Magnific-Popup: Can't close a gallery popup

Tags: meteor, magnific-popup

I'm trying to use [Magnific-Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) lightbox with my Meteor app.  The problem I have is that when I launch a gallery, I cannot close the gallery popup.  Clicking on the [x] button or clicking on the background has no effect.  Otherwise, the lightbox seems to work fine.  Using the single popup works as expected (including closing), but the gallery doesn't.  It's difficult to see what's going on because it crashes the Chrome inspector.  Sometimes I can see the following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The popup works fine if I set gallery=false in the code below, but obviously I lose gallery functionality...

Thank you.

html:

```
<div class="popup-gallery">
   <a href="{{imageURL}}">
      <img src="{{imageURL}}" alt="">
   </a>
    <a href="{{imageURL}}">
      <img src="{{imageURL}}" alt="">
   </a>
   <a href="{{imageURL}}">
      <img src="{{imageURL}}" alt="">
   </a>
</div>
```

js:

```
Template.itemPage.rendered = function() {
  console.log("itemPage rendered");

    $('#itemTiles').imagesLoaded(function() {

      $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
          enabled: true,
          navigateByImgClick: true,
          preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
        },
        image: {
          tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
          titleSrc: function(item) {
            return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by Test</small>';
          }
        }
      });
..
}
```

I have temporarily deployed the site to http://miyako.meteor.com/ just in case this helps.  This is my first foray into web development, so please excuse the messy code! :)

Comment: Try to update jQuery/Zepto/Magnific-Popup, or provide the link to page with issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great plugin!  I'm sure I'm doing something strange.  I believe I have the latest jQuery/Magnific-Popup, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I have deployed the site here: http://miyako.meteor.com/  .  I'm new to webdev, so please excuse the bad code....

Comment: Sorry, to explain, you will need to click on the "Maehama Beach" link to get to the detailed page.  On that page, a bunch of thumbnails will load up that will launch the gallery.  Thank you.

Comment: You've got all files packed and minified it's hard to debug this. jQuery is also isn't on latest version. Try to isolate the issue on jsfiddle, or exclude all third party scripts.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  I deployed it without the debug flag.  I re-deployed it for now with the debug flag, so it shouldnt be minified.  I will also try what you suggested!  Thank you

Comment: Ok, I manually changed the jquery and it seems to have done the trick!  Sorry for the trouble